# Winapi function to test uiAccess value

Tags: winapi

Hi all I'm trying to find a function in winapi manual that allows me to test if my program has uiAccess true or not, is there such a function?

Comment: There is no such function..  And uiAccess has to be specified statically in the app's UAC manifest, so why do you need to test for it dynamically at runtime?

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau is there a function to test if program is a service? Im trying to help someone on Firefox with jsctypes to SendInput special key combintations like ctrl+alt+del and alt+shift to change language but its not doing that, it seems it only works if its uiaccess or service. Im helping him here if you want to see whats up: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=14220287#p14220287

Comment: There is a fundamental difference in API coding requirements to run a program directly as a service. The program should implicitly know that it is a service just by the way it is coded and what APIs it calls. However, an exception to that would be if you are coding a normal console app and then running it as a service using `srvany.exe` or similar tool. In which case, the app cannot easily detect that it is being run as a service like that, without enumerating parent/child process hierarchies, etc.

Comment: But again, that is pretty useless to try, because a user-mode app is not supposed to be issuing system-reserved keystrokes in the first place, like `CTRL-ALT-DEL` and `ALT-SHIFT`. So the real question is, WHY does the other person need to send those keystrokes at all.  What is he really trying to accomplish, that other official APIs are not able to do?

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau I found this function here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd979761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx it says `If an application is not running as a service, it must be running as either the current user or the LocalSystem account to call SendSAS. ` so does this mean if the application is focused by the user I can call this function then the `SendInput` and it should work?

Comment: @RemyLebeau yeah Im not sure but he wants it done so I just thought it would be nice to accomplish it, good for open source knowledgebase. But one reason is because sending these keys is working fine on <=Win7 so he just wanted to be consistent for Win8+

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82250/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-noitidart).